# Finding distance between nodes of a graph in prolog

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I have a graph in Prolog represented by the edges & weights:

```
connected(a,b,2).
connected(b,e,1).
connected(b,l,5).
connected(b,g,2).
connected(c,s,2).
connected(d,a,2).
connected(d,k,4).
connected(d,l,7).
connected(e,m,2).
```

I need to write a predicate which takes a list of nodes & distance.

```
?- dist([a,b,e],X).
X=3
```

I've tried to write it, but it is very clumsy & doesn't give the intended result.

The basic idea I have is:
If it is a list of 2 elements then see if they are connected. 
If more then 2 elements in the list: see if the 1st element & 2nd element are connected,
recursively see if the next elements are connected.
I have defined 2 auxiliary predicates for head & tail.

```
dist([A, B], X) :-
    connected(A, B, X).
dist([A|B], Length) :-
    connected(A, hd(B,H,N), X),  % sees if A & next element in the list are connected
    dist(tl(B,H,N), Length1),    % recursive call with the list excluding element A
    Length is X + Length1.       

hd([H|T],H,Q).
tl([H|T],T,Q).
```

I am very new to Prolog land and I am still trying to comprehend the language semantics.
Please suggest an efficient way to go about this problem.

Comment: The `hd` and `tl` predicates don't make sense to me. The parameter `Q` isn't used, so it doesn't do anything. And predicates don't return values, so you can't write something like `connected(A, hd(B,H,N), X)`. Or rather, you can, but it doesn't mean what you think.

Comment: I was trying to use tail to denote the rest of the list after the first element. In your answer you've represented the list as '[A, B | T]'. Instead of that I was trying to get B by using head. The Q in the hd function was to return the value of head. 
I know it is all so clumsy :(  Hoping to learn faster,the logical programming way of doing things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
dist([_], 0).            % path of length 0 has distance 0
dist([A, B | T], L) :-
    connected(A, B, L1), % A and B are connected directly, the distance is L1
    dist([B|T], L2),     % the distance between B and the last element is L2
    L is L1 + L2.
```

Comment: Here in dist([B|T], L2), it automatically passes the element which is after B? How does that work?

Comment: Ok, I think predicate dist recurses till the base case..In the second recursion, the B in "dist([B|T], L2)", takes the place of A in "dist([A, B | T], L) :- " and its next element takes the place of B & so on till base case.

Comment: [B|T] denotes a path/list starting with element B and tail T (which is also a list of elements). The entire dist([B|T], L2) is therefore a sub-goal that attempts to find a path in the form of [B|T] with length L2.

Comment: @svick & @prusswan , I sort of get what you mean. I am trying to do the same thing but with a two lists of nodes.
That is, `?- distlist[[a,b,e],[b,d,l],X).
X=[3,12]` I am following the same logic but I am not able to figure out how to get the length as a list. If I post the code here it appears badly formated. Should I post an answer to the question or post it here itself?

Comment: @RBK, you should probably ask a new question for that.

Comment: I figured out how to do the same thing by imputing 2 lists as input.
Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: That should be "path of length 1", not 0, but +1 anyway.

Comment: @larsmans, I didn't mean that the list has a length of 0, but that the path has. And the length of a path is [defined as number of edges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28graph_theory%29) of the the path, not vertices.